# Why does adding the reciprocal of an equation to twice of itself give extra solutions?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Why does adding the reciprocal of an equation to twice of itself give extra solutions even though the reciprocal transformation is a one-to-one function? Is it because $2x + \frac{1}{x}$ is not a one-to-one function? Is there an easier explanation for students in Grade 9?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Essentially you started with $x-1=0$ and multiplied both sides by $2x+1$.  If you multiply $x-1=0$ by any polynomial, all the roots of the polynomial will become roots of the new equation.

Comment: Thanks, @RossMillikan! How about this more-complicated equation? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3089249/why-does-adding-an-equation-to-9-times-its-reciprocal-give-extra-solutions