# Why does adding an equation to 9 times its reciprocal give extra solutions?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Is it because $x + \frac{9}{x}$ is not a one-to-one function or transformation? Is there an easier explanation for students in Grade 9?

[image]

Comment: The question is really backwards.  The default assumption is that solutions you find by manipulating an equation arbitrarily will _not_ necessarily work in the original equation, unless you can prove some reason that they _do_ work.

Comment: As pointed out by amurius8312, squaring isn't the only way to create extra solutions. Take for example, $$x=3$$. Now if one were to take the sine of both sides...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the reason is exactly the fact that x+9/x is not one to one. 
Squaring is not the only transformation that can introduce false solutions. 
For 9th grade you could insist in what the "equivalent" transformations are  and that if one does any other he must check the solutions!